# How to prevent duplicates in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to transform my database entry creation inside **`NewsletterController.php`**:

```
$email = $request->input('email');
$table = DB::table('newsletters');
$table->insert(array('email' => $email, 'created_at' => now()));
```

to prevent duplicate entries. I tried doing this:

```
$table = DB::updateOrCreate('newsletters');
```

but this method does not seem to exist for `DB`. How would I do that?

Comment: why are you using `DB` and not the `newsletters` Elequent ? or you can simply set the `email` field in `newsletter` table as `unique`  and this will prevent dupplication automatically

Answer (score 1):

when you may want to update an existing record in the database or create it if no matching record exists. In this scenario, the [updateOrInsert](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#update-or-insert) method may be used. The updateOrInsert method accepts two arguments: an array of conditions by which to find the record, and an array of column and value pairs indicating the columns to be updated.

The updateOrInsert method will attempt to locate a matching database record using the first argument's column and value pairs. If the record exists, it will be updated with the values in the second argument. If the record can not be found, a new record will be inserted with the merged attributes of both arguments

```
 DB::updateOrInsert(['email'=>$eamil],['created_at'=>Carbon::now()]);
```

now, if email exists, the 'created_at' will be updated, otherwise a new row will be inserted with values of the merged array arguments

Answer (score 0):

`updateOrCreate` you use for Eloquent Builder and `updateOrInsert` you use for  Query Builder. Try with `updateOrInsert`.

```
$table = DB::updateOrInsert->table('newsletters')->([ 'id' => $request->id ], [
  'email' => $email,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Moussab Kbeisy**'s comment I can validate for `uniqueness` which will return a `422 error` if not met instead of inserting into the database:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required | unique:newsletters'
]);

$email = $request->input('email');
$table = DB::table('newsletters');
$table->insert(['email' => $email, 'created_at' => now()]);
```

Comment: You misunderstood the comment you are referring to.  The suggestion was to [create a unique index at the database level](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#creating-indexes) - this is standard practice for when you have a field which is supposed to be unique.  The other suggestion they made was to use [Eloquent models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent) instead of messing with `DB` and `insert`, then you could use `updateOrCreate()`, and would much simplify many other things.

Comment: I really suggest you try some tutorials, or even just [reading the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x), I think you are missing some pretty key, fundamental ideas which might help on your development journey.

Comment: Yes, I'm a noob. I will look into your suggestions. Thank you